# Counting "wells" in a numpy 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Given a 2D matrix of 1s and 0s, for e.g. -

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

1 indicates a block, and 0 indicates empty space.
I wish to calculate the **number of wells**, and their **accumulated depth**.

A well exists when a column is shorter than both its adjacent columns, borders are assumed to be filled with blocks (1s). For e.g., padding the borders, the array becomes:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

- The number of wells is **3** (*Column 1, 4, and (9,10)*).
- The depth of a well is `min(height(col_to_left), height(col_to_right)) - height(well_col)`.
  So, in this case, the depths are **[1, 1, 7]**. And therefore the accumulated depth is 1+1+7=**9**.

How would I go about finding this? I want to avoid using loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argmax` to get the positions of the first one in each column.

```
# find absolute depths
d = X.argmax(0)
# correct columns that are all zero
v = np.take_along_axis(X, d[None], 0)
d[v[0]==0] = len(X)
# pad and compute the col to next col changes
d = np.diff(np.concatenate([[0], d, [0]]))
# exclude no change
chng, = np.where(d)
# find down changes
dwn = d[chng]>0
# wells are where we go down and the next non zero change is up
well = dwn[:-1]&~dwn[1:]
# map back to unfiltered indices for left and right walls
l, r = chng[:-1][well], chng[1:][well]
wells = np.c_[l+1, r]
wells
# array([[ 1,  1],
#       [ 4,  4],
#       [ 9, 10]])
# retrieve relative depths
depths = np.minimum(d[l], -d[r])
depths
# array([1, 1, 7])
```